# OnMapReadyCallback not calling

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on google map v2. 
I implement OnMapReadyCallback in a custom map fragment but it's not trigger onMapReady once fragment start.

my code:

```
public class CustomMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener{
```

OnCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_custom_map, container, false);

    mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);


    return rootView;
}
```

Override method

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
    googleMap = mMap;

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LatLng mMyLocation = new LatLng(mLat, mLng);


    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(mMyLocation).zoom(13).build();
  googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


    Log.d("Map", "OnMapReady");
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

}
```

Search around but not luck.

Comment: `Log.d("Map", "OnMapReady");` not showing anythnig?

Comment: No, totally not showing. Thats I confirmed that OnMapReady not trigger at all.

Comment: Where are you testing this app?

Comment: Tested on my device.

Answer (score 1):

Apply couple of changes:

in `onCreateView()`  remove `mMapView.onResume();`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Now in `onResume()`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}
```

your `onMapReady()` looks ok.

Make sure you add this in xml:

```
  <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: tried. Still not trigger. I've added all lifecycle method. The map was shown but OnMapReady not trigger and camerazoom no works.